# Unable to use Docker DNS with nftables

Tags: docker, docker-networking

I have a bind9 DNS container running on 10.64.128.53, which is on the docker network "servers" on the subnet 10.64.128.0/24.  this works fine and if I run:
`nslookup google.com 10.64.128.53`

I get the output:

```
Server:         10.64.128.53
Address:        10.64.128.53#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.193.142
```

When I run the same command in a docker container: `docker run --rm -it --network servers --dns 10.64.128.53 alpine nslookup google.com 10.64.1 28.53`

I get the output:

```
Server:         10.64.128.53
Address:        10.64.128.53:53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.193.142
```

This is expected
Now if I run: `docker run --rm -it --network servers --dns 10.64.128.53 alpine nslookup google.com`
I get the output:

```
nslookup: write to '127.0.0.11': Connection refused
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

This doesn't make much sense to me because I specified my docker DNS server but I'm assuming that docker runs it through an internal proxy on 127.0.0.11.  This would be great if I was using it but I don't need it. The best solution I can think of is overwriting `/etc/resolv.conf` with my DNS server but this seems like an awful solution.  I saw this https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/19474#issuecomment-173093011 but can't get this working in nftables but I guess this is the only way because it seems the docker DNS server requires connections from 127.0.0.11:53

The host is Gentoo Linux, I know the networking works when iptables is installed. I see these errors in dockers's logs whenever I start a VM:

```
time="2022-01-25T03:08:56Z" level=warning msg="Failed to find iptables: exec: \"iptables\": executable file not found in $PATH"
time="2022-01-25T03:08:56Z" level=error msg="set up rule failed, [-t nat -I DOCKER_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11 -p udp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.11:50360]"
time="2022-01-25T03:08:56Z" level=error msg="set up rule failed, [-t nat -I DOCKER_POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.11 -p udp --sport 50360 -j SNAT --to-source :53]"
time="2022-01-25T03:08:56Z" level=error msg="set up rule failed, [-t nat -I DOCKER_OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.11 -p tcp --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.11:46531]"
time="2022-01-25T03:08:56Z" level=error msg="set up rule failed, [-t nat -I DOCKER_POSTROUTING -s 127.0.0.11 -p tcp --sport 46531 -j SNAT --to-source :53]"
```

I also see this error every time I try to run the nslookup commands in the docker containers but I'm not sure how related it is:

```
time="2022-01-25T03:20:08.094540639Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.41/exec/d52b964c2e34acb78b67e5d2f02a8143e1efb3c45da0936fe128ed14fb6296ce/resize returned error: cannot resize a stopped container: unknown"
```

Just using iptables isn't really a solution here, I want it to be purely nftables and that doesn't seem unreasonable.

If I have iptables running, Docker DNS seems to work but there are no rules added to iptables.  I don't understand this, why does it require iptables but make no rules?

Comment: Docker doesn't support `nftables`.

Comment: That isn't helpful.  There should be a way to use purely nftables with docker, iptables and nftables are both similar enough.

Comment: Docker heavily depends on `iptables` to configure its networking but it doesn't support `nftables` at all. If you search google `site:docs.docker.com nftables` you'll find exactly one hit.

Comment: Everything but DNS works perfectly with nftables, the issue here is that docker uses hacks to get internal DNS working

Comment: I have a mostly identical setup with Gentoo without the legacy iptables kernel option and the only way I get Docker to actually work is to alter containers' entrypoint to fix the `/etc/resolve.conf` before starting up the real entrypoint. I'm stumped that Docker is this dirty especially when they supposedly have an option in the daemon config to not alter iptables configuration which is mostly disregarded anyway.

Comment: @Ginnungagap what is your exact method for altering the container's resolv.conf? I agree it shouldn't have to be this dirty.  I feel like specifying dns options should just overwrite resolv.conf or something instead of docker using the dns proxying inside